# the requested URL was not found on this server django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I am following a youtube tutorial, and am getting an error...

getting an error

```
The requested URL /hello was not found on this server.
```

site/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/$', article.views.hello),
    ...
)
```

article/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
  name = 'mike'
  html = '<html><body> sup %s </body></html> ' %name
  return HttpRequest(html)
```

site/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'article',
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request url `/hello` does not have a trailing slash (`/`). You can make the url pattern match `/` optionally by appending `?`:

```
url(r'^hello/?$', article.views.hello),
```

Comment: Wow. localhost/hello was the issue.. I am supposed to use localhost:8000/hello ....aaahhh